# copying contents from one char array to another but getting junk

Tags: c++, arrays, getline, c-strings

I am accepting a user input in the format `(123) 456-7890` and storing it into a char array per my assigned instructions.  I want to copy JUST THE NUMBERS of that input into another array so I have `1234567890` and leave out the `( ) -`.

I get the originally formatted user input by using `cin.getline()` and I use a `for` loop to transfer just the numbers into the second array but I get a bizarre output.  Here is the code:

```
int main()
{
    const int MAX = 15, dMAX = 10;

    char nums[MAX], digit[dMAX];
    int usableN, rdx = 0;


    cout << "Enter phone number in (XXX) XXX-XXXX format:  ";
    cin.getline(nums, MAX);

    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
    {
        digit[rdx] = nums[i];
        usableN = atoi(digit);
        cout << digit << endl;
        rdx++;
    }

    for (int i = 6; i < 9; i++)
    {
        digit[rdx] = nums[i];
        usableN = atoi(digit);
        cout << digit << endl;
        rdx++;
    }

    for (int i = 10; i < 14; i++)
    {
        digit[rdx] = nums[i];
        usableN = atoi(digit);
        cout << digit << endl;
        rdx++;
    }

    cout << endl << digit << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

For now, ignore `usableN = atoi(digit);` because that is for later use. The multiple `cout <<` parts are so I can see what is being stored at each step. Now, this is the part I can't understand and need help with:

My output is full of junk and despite the fact that I used `const int dMAX = 10;` my array is 24 characters long. Here is the output:

```
7Ss╨vJs╨vπ(789) 678-1234
78s╨vJs╨vπ(789) 678-1234
789╨vJs╨vπ(789) 678-1234
7896vJs╨vπ(789) 678-1234
78967Js╨vπ(789) 678-1234
789678s╨vπ(789) 678-1234
7896781╨vπ(789) 678-1234
78967812vπ(789) 678-1234
789678123π(789) 678-1234
7896781234(789) 678-1234

7896781234(789) 678-1234
```

Why is it copying the entirety of `nums[]` on the tail of `digit[]` ?

How do I get a clean array with just the `7896781234` in it?

Also, I noticed that whenever I `cin.getline(nums, MAX)`, if the user inputs more than `MAX` characters, it crashes!  Why is this and how do I prevent this?

I thought that `cin.getline` would only store the fist nth characters defined by `MAX`

Sorry, this was a lengthy explanation but I wanted to make sure I was clear on what I was asking. Thanks in advance for any help on these issues.

Comment: Read up on *null termination* of strings

Comment: cin.getline throws if input is longer than countsize, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline

Comment: Thank you.  I tried to read that but couldn't make much sense of it. I see it sets a failbit but how do I prevent a user input > countsize? does getline have a feature where I can limit the number of characters it reads in from the keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure your strings are always null terminated.  For example:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
{
    digit[rdx] = nums[i];
    digit[rdx+1] = '\0';
    usableN = atoi(digit);
    cout << digit << endl;
    rdx++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, now it is pretty.  Does anyone have any solutions about my `getline`?

Comment: @Greg: I'm not able to reproduce the crash with long input, and I don't see any issue there.  What line is it crashing on?

Comment: It is here:   `cin.getline(nums, MAX)`  If the user inputs say, `12345678901234567` then that is larger than `MAX` so it just fills up the screen with junk and I am trying to find a way to prevent it if a user chooses to enter a bunch of characters.  Does `getline()` have a feature that will limit the number of characters it accepts and ignore the rest?  Thanks again!

Comment: @Greg: I don't get a crash with that input after fixing the null termination issue in your program (three places).  Yes, `cin.getline` does work as you expect and only reads up to MAX characters.

Comment: You're right! It works now.  I'm still confused though how fixing the null termination of `digit[]` affected `nums[]` especially since the `getline()` is before the fix.  Thank you, nonetheless.

Comment: @Greg: Once you tried to print the non-terminated string, you were accessing uninitialized characters, which is undefined behavior.  Once you have undefined behavior, anything can happen.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in C/C++ have to be null terminated (their last character has to be 0) for most of the standard library (and probably your) code to work properly. That means that you need to check if you have reached the last character on the string by checking if the character you are currently reading == NULL or 0 as in this example:

```
char String = "My string";
for(int i = 0; String[i] != 0; ++i)
{
  std::cout << "Printing a character: " << String[i] << std::endl;
}
```

That example will run until it prints all characters in the string. Note how the NULL or 0 character marks the end of the string.

When you read an array with more characters than MAX probably you are probably overwriting that last 0 character and your program and that is causing a buffer overrun and consequently a crash, since your OS detects you are trying to access memory you are not supposed to access and it shuts your program down.

You should probably consider using an standard string (std::string) instead of a char array, since those grow automatically and work with getline by default.

As for your printed values having weird errors is probably related to the buffer overrun I mentioned earlier.